# Acronym of abbreviation for "At the time of writing this document"?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

I'm wondering if there is some special abbreviation for "At the time of writing this document".
I am writing a document that contains names of individuals to contact in certain scenarios, and it is labeled with its date of creation.

I want to be explicit though about who should be contacted, but remind some potential reader this may have changed if said contact leaves the company or is replaced. Or if there is some kind of global fallout.

Proposal if this doesn't exist: ATTOW - **A**t **T**he **T**ime **O**f **W**riting this document.

Comment: Since the information wouldn't have been placed *after* the time of writing, and if the information was checked close to the time of writing, it is almost redundant to explicitly state that it was correct *at the time of writing*. Try a different tack by adding a disclaimer: *information subject to change*.

Comment: What would be gained by introducing this new acronym (or initialism) if your readers won't understand it? I recommend identifying the roles/offices/positions to be contacted (by title or definition), with an addendum stating that as of (this date), the following contact information is accurate - and then listing the individuals occupying the roles or holding the offices indicated in the main document... and perhaps recommending quarterly or annual updates to the contact details.

Comment: As a practical matter, you could direct readers to where they can find current information. That kills two birds with one stone.

Comment: Update your document when things change. It's unlikely people are reading for historical purposes.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to include dated material in a relatively permanent document. Consider something like "Contact the High Commissioner of Rumtifoo, *currently Ms. Helen Huntforit...*"

Comment: @Rob_Ster, I like this idea with the italics. I'll do it. Lawrence: also good points. I didn't think of it being redundant at first but it is.

Comment: The usual expression is: at the time of this writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ATTOW**   At the Time of Writing [FreeDictionary](https://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/At+the+Time+of+Writing) and [AcronymFinder](https://www.acronymfinder.com/At-the-Time-of-Writing-(ATTOW).html)

It should be pointed out that the latter link includes

> This definition appears very rarely and is found in the following
> Acronym Finder categories:
>
> Slang/chat, popular culture

and that the former link merely references the second.